# Spring Integration - Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel

Tags: spring-integration

A very simple example with Spring Integration 5.3.2: a single integration flow, registered using the spring-integration DSL with the IntegrationFlowContext:

`

```
    MessageChannel startChannel = MessageChannels.direct("channel").get();

    StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(startChannel)
            .log().get();

    flowContext.registration(flow)
            .autoStartup(false)
            .register();

    flow.start();

    startChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").build());`
```

Yields  `org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel`.

Why? Adding a single `.transform(e->e)` (for example) resolves the problem, but obviously is a strange workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s definitely an expected behavior. You declare a `MessageChannel` and send a message into it, but there are no subscribers declared for that channel . Therefore you really see a difference when you add that `transform()`. You should decide for yourself what is your logic and what you would like to do when there is the message in that channel. You may consider to use other channel types, but still consider to process messages somehow.

Comment: Thanks. It's not always clear to me what counts as a subscriber and what does not.

Comment: See `log()` JavaDocs: it is a channel interceptor not an endpoint with a subscriber

Comment: Thanks. I fear I have more questions, but I'll start them in different StackOverflow threads.